# How to mock a method from a helper in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

Consider the following code used in a gem, a dependency of our main app:

```
module Module1
  module Module2
    module EnvInit
      def stub_env(name, value)
        stub_const('ENV', ENV.to_hash.merge(name => value))
      end
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Module1::Module2::EnvInit
  config.before(:each) do
    stub_env('NAME', 'John Doe')
  end
end
```

Our main app uses .env files for our environment variables. However, the code above overrides `ENV['NAME']` for some reason. We do not have access to this gem, so in order for our test to persist I wanted to mock when `stub_env` is called, like so:

```
before do
  # tried this with `allow_any_instance_of` as well
  allow(Module1::Module2::EnvInit).to receive(:stub_env).with('NAME','John Wayne')
end
```

OR

```
it "should match name to John Wayne" do
  EnvInit.any_instance.should_receive(:stub_env).with('NAME','John Wayne')
end
```

etc. I've tried various ways of mocking but none of my attempts to target `stub_env` works. All `stub_env` sees is `John Doe`.

Simply put, I want `stub_env` to receive `value == John Wayne` by way of mocks.

Comment: The `RSpec.configure` part probably comes from one the gem's spec files. You should not include those files in your application. And if including the gem automatically adds the gem's test setup, it's a serious bug that should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Mocking is a process of changing the default behaviour to what you have desired. That said, you want to mock `stub_env`, **receiving `John Doe`** (as it is receiving `"John Doe"` in real life) and do putting `"John Wayne"` in the `ENV` instead.

```
allow_any_instance_of(Module1::Module2::EnvInit).to \
  receive(:stub_env).
    with('NAME', 'John Doe').
    and_return stub_const('ENV', ENV.to_hash.merge('NAME => 'John Wayne'))
```

Comment: I tried this just now but no dice. You seem to be returning the same `stub_const` line with the value I want to persist (John Wayne), and with another change being the value being supplied via with() to the one that is hard coded. Still wasn't able to target the method in question.

Comment: One can’t mock callers. One can mock callees. Also, I do not follow why the approach above did not work for you.

Comment: The ideal solution for me would be placing binding.pry on line 5, just before `stub_const('ENV', ENV.to_hash.merge(name => value))` and verying that `value` returns `John Wayne`. With your suggestion, `value==John Doe`. If I `exit`, my test fails.

Thanks for looking into it. I look forward to getting back at this conversation first thing tomorrow.